# Android error: package android.os does not exist

Tags: android-studio, bundle

I have imported a project to Android Studio using Gradle. Import process was successful, but it gives an error for `android.os.*`, when I try to import it.
It is a libGDX project.

Comment: Did you set Android SDK properly? Try using any Android widget.

Comment: Yes, I have set SDK. Which widgets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recently, I met a similar case in Android Studio 3.2.1 Ubuntu/Linux version.

I am quite sure about the issue shall be related to the Android SDK installation,because I build the same project in Android Studio of my Windows 10 laptop.

Issue:
Java compiler error at Android studio

```
error: package android.os does not exist
error: package android.media does not exist
error: package android.content does not exist
error: package android.util does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable Log
error: cannot find symbol class Context
error: cannot find symbol class AudioRecord
```

Solution:
The android.jar which was mentioned at the build.gradle file was not installed at the /sdk/platforms/ directory. See the android.jar dependency at my  build.gradle file below(which caused the issue),

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files(sdkDir+'/platforms/android-24/android.jar')
}
```

Install the correct android platform(correct API level as mentioned in the build.gradle file,if any) and rebuild the project.

Comment: Error could also be caused due to java version in the "compileOptions" section of build.gradle. Try using the value "JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8" for both "sourceCompatibility" and "targetCompatibility".

Comment: Got this to work as: `implementation files("/usr/local/<companyname>/home/<username>/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar")`

Comment: For me what worked was going to `Users/{username}/appData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android31` then double clicking on `android.jar` and opening it with `openJDK Platform Binary` then I tried rebuilding the app and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest to use AGP Upgrade assistent.
I often have probs upgrading gradle. This time with artic fox and java 11 it I got all those infamous android.* not found errors.

Then I discovered that neat AGP Upgrade assistent (in tools since Studio 4.2) - and it did what it should and everything is now using gradle 7 and compiles again.

About time such a tool was introduced - and I just saw about half a year too late ;)

Comment: Android Studio -> Tools -> AGP Upgrade Assistant...

Comment: This helped me, Thanks  @EvgeniiVorobei and FrankKrumnow

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was showing same kind of error with `android.content.context`

I figured out that the issue is I was using old gradle version with below android params in build.gradle

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

So I removed this and the error is no more.

Answer (score 1):

I am building from an old article, https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676, and it doesn't yet have a build.gradle file, but I had the same error. I solved it by changing the compile command in my Makefile to:

```
classes: $(SOURCES)
    javac -d obj \
     -source 1.6 \
     -target 1.8 \
     -classpath src \
     -bootclasspath $(ANDROID) \
     $+
```

where `ANDROID` is /usr/local/src/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar.

I get warnings now that source value 6 is obsolete, but at least it compiles.

Comment: `Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath` -- something also was not included like JDK libs?