# Compilation error: Android libraries are not being included in the intellij plugin project (java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins, intellij-plugin

I want to access the hardware features of android device in intellij idea through folllowing code.

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;        

Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Display : ", Build.DISPLAY);
```

When I include this in my action class this gives me an compilatrion error like:
I have also include android sdk in the project structure of intellij-plugin-project...

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

error: package android.os does not exist
error: package android.util does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable Build
error: cannot find symbol variable Log

Comment: The snippet you added should work.
It might be helpful if you shared the compiler error outputs.

Comment: edited. can you please review it now...@isaaaaame

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307414/android-error-package-android-os-does-not-exist)